# Error loading attribute based SLD consisting of 7 classes to GeoServer styles

Tags: geoserver, sld

I've got a line data published through GeoServer. I'd like style it based on 7 numerical intervals by using one of the columns. I classify symbology accordingly and export to sld to use it with GeoServer. Then I copy/paste that into SLD editor on GeoServer.

Next, I click to validate, but nothing happens. Not even an error message. Then, deleting two block of categories (or rules with SLD terminology) and clicking, this time it validates with no issues. I tried everything but could not get any response when I try to validate or save it with 7 or 6 classes. Only validates true if there is 5 or less categories/rules defined.

Did anyone else experience this issue before?

Edit:
One of the sld's I created by exporting the style directly from QGIS is below. i.e. nothing manual did I to create this sld.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>roughness</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>roughness</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0.2 - 1</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0.2 - 1</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.20000000000000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.99990000000000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#1a9641</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1 - 2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1 - 2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.99990000000000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.99990000000000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#77c35c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>2 - 3</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>2 - 3</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.99990000000000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2.99989999999999979</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#c4e687</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>3 - 6</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>3 - 6</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2.99989999999999979</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffc0</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>6 - 9</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>6 - 9</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#fec981</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>9 - 12</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>9 - 12</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#f07c4a</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>12 - 100</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>12 - 100</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>long_term_</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d7191c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: please add your sld to your question, and the relevant part of the log file

Answer (score 0):

Solved 2 days later. The main problem was about limiting access to Geoserver services. My advice would be to grant access all services and instead tweak data limitations.